# Update query is not working in Mysql but instead inserting new data in this query

Tags: php, mysql

Table name = image_2017.My image is not updating by this UPDATE query in a particular `$_GET['id']` instead image is inserting as a new image. I don't know what is wrong in this code.I am new to php. Kindly help me someone.

```
<?php

include_once "config.php";
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    header("index.php");
}

    $id = $_GET['id'];    
    //echo $id;

    if(!empty($_FILES)){
        $t = time();
        $filename = $category."_".$t."_".$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $upload = "uploads/";
        $fileupload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$upload.$filename);
        if($fileupload){

            $msg1 = "File uploaded Successfully";
        }else{
            $msg2 = "File uploaded Failed";
        }
    }


    if(!empty($_POST)){

    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $image = $_FILES['image'];

         $query = "UPDATE image_2017 SET category ='$category', image ='$filename' WHERE id ='$id' ";
         $result = $db->query($query);
         if($result){

            $msg3 = "Image Updated Successfully";

         }else{

            $msg4 = "Image not Updated";

         }

        }else{
            //echo "Please enter all the details";
        }

 ?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form class="form news" style="padding:10px;" method="post" action="image-2017.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">category</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select class="form-control" name="category">
                            <option>--> Select <--</option>
                            <option>Birthday</option>
                            <option>Christmas</option>
                            <option>Fruits</option>
                            <option>Ganesh Chathurthi</option>
                            <option>Green Day</option>
                            <option>Guitar Play</option>
                            <option>Independence Day</option>
                            <option>Krishna Jayanthi</option>
                            <option>Onam</option>
                            <option>Splash Pool</option>
                            <option>Teddy Bear</option>
                            <option>Veg Market</option>
                            <option>Vijayadhasami</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <br>
            <div class="row">    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Upload Image</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="file" name="image">   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        <a href="image-2017.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Back</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @did you get any error? Also above your code at `$filename = $category."_".$t."_".$_FILES['image']['name'];`. you didn't set $category variable.

you have to set `$category = $_POST['category'];` above validating `$_FILES`.

Comment: No i am not getting any error. image is not updating in a particular $_GET['id']. But instead new image is inserting. I dont know why it is happening.

Comment: The code which you've shared is a partial code or full code ?

Comment: if you are using phpmyadmin , or such try adding a random query like `UPDATE image_2017 SET category ='1', image ='xyz' WHERE id ='1'` and check for errors

Comment: maybe you are not using correct html, there is no where input for `id` in html . you should have something like `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">`

Comment: Just for testing, comment your UPDATE code & execute the file & see what's happening? it's still inserting record in table or not ?

Comment: in phpmyadmin this code is now working as Mr.Darshan Jain said.

Comment: then probably you are not using correct html.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart . as u said i commented the update query and executed the file new image is inserting. how it is happening.

Comment: is any wrong in this php & html code ?

Comment: try my answer, if it works

Comment: Finally i found how the error comes. if i write action="#" in html form update query is working. but if i write action="image-2017.php" update is not working and it is using the insert query which i used in "image-2017.php". Anyhow Thank you to Manish,  mi6crazyheart, Darshan Jain.

Comment: Is there an image_2016?

Comment: no its a table name. the problem is solved now. thank u.

Answer (score 0):

I updated html to add a `post` for `id`

```
<?php

include_once "config.php";
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    header("index.php");
}

    $id = $_POST['id'];    
    //echo $id;

    if(!empty($_FILES)){
        $t = time();
        $filename = $category."_".$t."_".$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $upload = "uploads/";
        $fileupload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$upload.$filename);
        if($fileupload){

            $msg1 = "File uploaded Successfully";
        }else{
            $msg2 = "File uploaded Failed";
        }
    }


    if(!empty($_POST)){

    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $image = $_FILES['image'];

         $query = "UPDATE image_2017 SET category ='$category', image ='$filename' WHERE id ='$id' ";
         $result = $db->query($query);
         if($result){

            $msg3 = "Image Updated Successfully";

         }else{

            $msg4 = "Image not Updated";

         }

        }else{
            //echo "Please enter all the details";
        }

 ?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form class="form news" style="padding:10px;" method="post" action="image-2017.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">category</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select class="form-control" name="category">
                            <option>--> Select <--</option>
                            <option>Birthday</option>
                            <option>Christmas</option>
                            <option>Fruits</option>
                            <option>Ganesh Chathurthi</option>
                            <option>Green Day</option>
                            <option>Guitar Play</option>
                            <option>Independence Day</option>
                            <option>Krishna Jayanthi</option>
                            <option>Onam</option>
                            <option>Splash Pool</option>
                            <option>Teddy Bear</option>
                            <option>Veg Market</option>
                            <option>Vijayadhasami</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <br>
            <div class="row">    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Upload Image</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="file" name="image">   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        <a href="image-2017.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Back</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Make sure you reach the page as: `mypage.php?id=12`